# Is It possible to make a horizontal slider form with Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-forms

I have searched through the Django documentation, and can't find any Field for a slider. I wish to have 8 sliders with a 5 value range. I can't find any examples of one, and don't have any experience on making custom form Fields. How would I go about doing this? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qIQ2.png) is an image on what I mean by horizontal slider.

I attempted to use javascript to handle the sliders but ran into a wall when it came to collecting and sending this data back to the view in order to update model attributes.